# Difference Between Lyapunov and Strong Lyapunov Function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, special-functions, mathematical-modeling

Good Day everyone. I was assigned to show that given an autonomous system of Differential Equations and a function $V$, I need to show that $V$ is Lyapunov function.

To show that $V$ is Lyapunov. I will show the following: (there is no problem here)

1. $V$ and its first partial derivatives are continuous.
2. $V$ is positive definite.
3. $\dot{V}$ (given by certain equation) is negative definite.

On a domain $D$ on the xy-plane containing $(0,0)$, then $V$ is a Lyapunov Function. However, the question that I need to answer is followed by: is it a strong Lyapunov Function (I do not know how to show that a function is strong Lyapunov)?

My question is, what is the difference between Lyapunov and Strong Lyapunov Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to refer the exact definition given in your course, because it is not a standard notion.

One of possibilities is that if $\vec x(t)$ is the solution of your differential equation, then you will have $$\frac{d}{dt}V(\vec x(t))\le 0$$ for Lyapunov function and $$\frac{d}{dt}V(\vec x(t))< 0 \text{ whenever }x\ne 0$$ for strong Lyapunov function.

Another possibility would be to say that we impose $\nabla V( x)\cdot x \le -c\|x\|^2$ for strong Lyapunov functions (as in strong convexity).